# Try to process multiple strings from pandas dataframe seperately from each other and create triples from it

Tags: python, neo4j, spacy, coreference-resolution

I have a question.

I want to create triples from a review dataset and visualize the relationships within the reviews, seperately from each other.

Apologies for the huge amount of code, but this is required to succesfully process the triple extractor.

```
    import spacy
    import crosslingual_coreference

    DEVICE = -1 # Number of the GPU, -1 if want to use CPU

    # Add coreference resolution model
    coref = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['ner', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'])
    coref.add_pipe(
        "xx_coref", config={"device": DEVICE})
    #part 2
    def call_wiki_api(item):
    try:
        url = f"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search={item}&language=en&format=json"
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        # Return the first id (Could upgrade this in the future)
        return data['search'][0]['id']
    except:
        return 'id-less'
    #part 3
    import re
    from typing import List

    from spacy import Language, util
    from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span
    from transformers import pipeline


    def extract_triplets(text: str) -> List[str]:
        """
        parses the text to triplets
        1. Split the text into tokens
        2. If the token is <triplet>, <subj>, or <obj>, then set the current variable to the appropriate value
        3. If the token is not one of the above, then append it to the appropriate variable
        4. If the current variable is <subj>, then append the triplet to the list of triplets
        :param text: str - the text to be parsed
        :type text: str
        :return: A list of dictionaries.
        """
        triplets = []
        relation, subject, relation, object_ = "", "", "", ""
        text = text.strip()
        current = "x"
        for token in text.replace("<s>", "").replace("<pad>", "").replace("</s>", "").split():
            if token == "<triplet>":
                current = "t"
                if relation != "":
                    triplets.append(
                        {"head": subject.strip(), "type": relation.strip(), "tail": object_.strip()}
                    )
                    relation = ""
                subject = ""
            elif token == "<subj>":
                current = "s"
                if relation != "":
                    triplets.append(
                        {"head": subject.strip(), "type": relation.strip(), "tail": object_.strip()}
                    )
                object_ = ""
            elif token == "<obj>":
                current = "o"
                relation = ""
            else:
                if current == "t":
                    subject += " " + token
                elif current == "s":
                    object_ += " " + token
                elif current == "o":
                    relation += " " + token
        if subject != "" and relation != "" and object_ != "":
            triplets.append(
                {"head": subject.strip(), "type": relation.strip(), "tail": object_.strip()}
            )

        return triplets


    @Language.factory(
        "rebel",
        requires=["doc.sents"],
        assigns=["doc._.rel"],
        default_config={
            "model_name": "Babelscape/rebel-large",
            "device": 0,
        },
    )
    class RebelComponent:
        def __init__(
            self,
            nlp,
            name,
            model_name: str,
            device: int,
        ):
            assert model_name is not None, ""
            self.triplet_extractor = pipeline(
                "text2text-generation", model=model_name, tokenizer=model_name, device=device
            )
            # Register custom extension on the Doc
            if not Doc.has_extension("rel"):
                Doc.set_extension("rel", default={})

        def _generate_triplets(self, sents: List[Span]) -> List[List[dict]]:
            """
            1. We pass the text of the sentence to the triplet extractor.
            2. The triplet extractor returns a list of dictionaries.
            3. We extract the token ids from the dictionaries.
            4. We decode the token ids into text.
            5. We extract the triplets from the text.
            6. We return the triplets.
            The triplet extractor is a model that takes a sentence as input and returns a list of dictionaries.
            Each dictionary contains the token ids of the extracted triplets.
            The token ids are the numbers that represent the words in the sentence.
            For example, the token id of the word "the" is 2.
            The token ids are decoded into text using the tokenizer.
            The tokenizer is a model that takes a list of token ids as input and returns a list of words.
            :param sents: List[Span]
            :type sents: List[Span]
            :return: A list of lists of dicts.
            """
            output_ids = self.triplet_extractor(
                [sent.text for sent in sents], return_tensors=True, return_text=False
            )  # [0]["generated_token_ids"]
            extracted_texts = self.triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode(
                [out["generated_token_ids"] for out in output_ids]
            )
            extracted_triplets = []
            for text in extracted_texts:
                extracted_triplets.extend(extract_triplets(text))
            return extracted_triplets

        def set_annotations(self, doc: Doc, triplets: List[dict]):
            """
            The function takes a spacy Doc object and a list of triplets (dictionaries) as input.
            For each triplet, it finds the substring in the Doc object that matches the head and tail of the triplet.
            It then creates a spacy span object for each of the head and tail.
            Finally, it creates a dictionary of the relation type, head span and tail span and adds it to the Doc object
            :param doc: the spacy Doc object
            :type doc: Doc
            :param triplets: List[dict]
            :type triplets: List[dict]
            """
            for triplet in triplets:
                # get substring to spacy span
                head_span = re.search(triplet["head"], doc.text)
                tail_span = re.search(triplet["tail"], doc.text)
                # get spacy span
                if head_span is not None:
                    head_span = doc.char_span(head_span.start(), head_span.end())
                else:
                    head_span = triplet["head"]
                if tail_span is not None:
                    tail_span = doc.char_span(tail_span.start(), tail_span.end())
                else:
                    tail_span = triplet["tail"]
                offset = (head_span.start, tail_span.start)
                if offset not in doc._.rel:
                    doc._.rel[offset] = {
                        "relation": triplet["type"],
                        "head_span": head_span,
                        "tail_span": tail_span,
                    }

        def __call__(self, doc: Doc) -> Doc:
            """
            The function takes a doc object and returns a doc object
            :param doc: Doc
            :type doc: Doc
            :return: A Doc object with the sentence triplets added as annotations.
            """
            sentence_triplets = self._generate_triplets(doc.sents)
            self.set_annotations(doc, sentence_triplets)
            return doc

        def pipe(self, stream, batch_size=128):
            """
            It takes a stream of documents, and for each document,
            it generates a list of sentence triplets,
            and then sets the annotations for each sentence in the document
            :param stream: a generator of Doc objects
            :param batch_size: The number of documents to process at a time, defaults to 128 (optional)
            """
            for docs in util.minibatch(stream, size=batch_size):
                sents = []
                for doc in docs:
                    sents += doc.sents
                sentence_triplets = self._generate_triplets(sents)
                index = 0
                for doc in docs:
                    n_sent = len(list(doc.sents))
                    self.set_annotations(doc, sentence_triplets[index : index + n_sent])
                    index += n_sent
                    yield doc
```

The following code is also required.

```
    # Define rel extraction model

    rel_ext = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['ner', 'lemmatizer', 'attribute_rules', 'tagger'])
    rel_ext.add_pipe("rebel", config={
        'device':DEVICE, # Number of the GPU, -1 if want to use CPU
        'model_name':'Babelscape/rebel-large'} # Model used, will default to 'Babelscape/rebel-large' if not given
        )
```

This creates the following triple extractor.

```
    input_text = "Christian Drosten works in Germany. He likes to work for Google."
    coref_text = coref(input_text)._.resolved_text
    doc = rel_ext(coref_text)

    for value, rel_dict in doc._.rel.items():
        print(f"{value}: {rel_dict}")
        
    # {'relation': 'country of citizenship', 'head_span': {'text': 'Christian Drosten', 'id': 'Q1079331'}, 'tail_span': {'text': 'Germany', 'id': 'Q183'}}
    # {'relation': 'employer', 'head_span': {'text': 'Christian Drosten', 'id': 'Q1079331'}, 'tail_span': {'text': 'Google', 'id': 'Q95'}}
```

Now, assume that I want to process the following dictionary, with the individual reviews seperately from each other as the input_text. Is there anyway to creates triple from the reviews individually? If so, how would this be possible?

reviews = {0: 'Too Heavy and Poor weld quality,',
1: 'difficult mount',
2: 'just got it installed',
3: 'Decent Little Reader, Poor Tablet',
4: 'Ok For What It Is'}

Looking forward for your response.

Kind regards

Comment: Maybe what you really need is a beginner intro to python

Comment: Ok. So you do not have a recommendation on how to get triples from multiple texts, such as the rows in a pandas dataframe that contain strings that do not have a connection to the other rows in a dataframe?

Comment: Maybe you're right. Do you have any recommendation how the output of the nlp pipeline of Rebel can be processed in Neo4j with Apoc? As this is the output of the NLP pipeline; {'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Barcelona}. If it would be better I can open a new question and explain it further.